# Proving Hensel's Lemma in a special case

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-writing

According to a [proof sketched in nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hensel%27s%20lemma), the general form of Hensel's Lemma (concerning polynomials, not power series) can eventually be reduced to the following special case:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I$ an ideal satisfying $I^2 = 0$, and let $f \in R[X]$ be a monic polynomial. Then any factorization $\overline{f} = gh$ into strongly coprime (*) monic polynomials $g,h \in (R/I)[X]$ can be lifted to a factorization $f = g'h'$ of $f$ into monic polynomials $g',h' \in R[X]$ with $\overline{g'} = g$ and $\overline{h'} = h$.

(*) Two polynomials are strongly coprime, if they generate the unit ideal (i.e. Bézout's identity holds).

I was trying to prove that statement, and I already managed to find polynomials $g'', h''$ lifting $g,h$ such that $f = g''h''$. However, I cannot guarantee that $g''$ and $h''$ are monic.

**incomplete proof:**

> Let $g',h' \in R[X]$ be monic polynomials lifting $g,h$. Then $f-g'h' =: r \in I[X]$. Since $g$ and $h$ are strongly coprime and $I$ is nilpotent, $g'$ and $h'$ are strongly coprime as well, i.e. we have $1 = g's + h't$ for certain $s,t \in R[X]$. Now set $g'' := g' + tr$ and $h'' := h' + sr$. Then we have $\overline{g''} = g$, $\overline{h''} = h$, and
>   $$ g''h'' = (g' + tr)(h' + sr) = g'h' + r(g's + h't) + str^2 = g'h'+r = f. $$

I realize that that many quantities in this proof are chosen fairly arbitrary. By choosing $g', h', s$, and $t$ more carefully, we get bounds on the degrees of $r,s$ and $t$. However, I wasn't able yet to get $\deg(tr) < \deg(g)$ and $\deg(sr) < \deg(h)$ which I need to ensure that $g''$ and $h''$ are monic.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it helps, you don't need both inequalities; if you can prove $g''$ has a unit for the leading coefficient, then $g''h'' = f$ implies that $h''$ has a unit for the leading coefficient as well.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, that actually helped! Tank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked up Bourbaki's proof. They use the following lemma, which I wasn't aware of:

> **Lemma:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $g,h \in R[X]$ strongly coprime polynomials, where $g$ is monic. Then every polynomial $r \in R[X]$ may be written **uniquely** in the form
>   $$ r = gs + ht, $$
>   where $s,t \in R[X]$ with $\deg{t} < \deg{g}$.

Let's apply that lemma in the setting above.

> As before, we choose $g',h' \in R[X]$ monic, lifting $g,h \in (R/I)[X]$. As $g$ and $h$ are strongly coprime, $g'$ and $h'$ are strongly coprime as well. We apply the lemma to get polynomials $s,t \in R[X]$ with $\deg(t) < \deg(g') = \deg(g)$ such that
>   $$ f - g'h' = g's + h't. $$
>   Reduction modulo $I$ gives
>   $$ 0 = g \overline{s} + h \overline{t}. $$
>   By the uniqueness part of the lemma we conclude $\overline{s} = \overline{t} = 0$, whence $s,t \in I[X]$. As before, it is easily verified that
>   $$ (g'+t)(h'+s) = g'h' + g's + h't + st = f, $$
>   so $g'' = g'+t$ and $h'' = h'+s$ are polynomials lifting $g,h$ whose product is $f$. But this time $g''$ is monic by construction (since $\deg(t) < \deg(g')$), and so $h''$ must be monic as well.

Comment: This seems like a straight-forward lemma to me. You use $s$ to scale $g$ so that it cancels the first few terms of $r$, use the division algorithm to fill out $t$, and then either the division algorithm or Bezut to finish the trailing terms of $s$. The fact that you can do this process and not have a remainder is where strongly coprime is used, and the fact that you can scale $g$ to match the first term of $r$ is where monicness is used as otherwise you don't know that the leading coefficients divide each other. Do you think it's more complicated than that?

Comment: @StellaBiderman The existence of such a pair (s,t) - ignoring the degree bound on t - is given by definition of strongly coprime. The degree bound on t can be established by polynomial division of t by g (here we need that g is monic). The uniqueness part is more interesting: Here we need that g and h are strongly coprime again, since then $g \mid ht$ implies $g \mid t$. But all in all, there is nothing complicated about that lemma.